# Azure bicep and parameter

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-bicep

Is there a way to add a resourceid as a parameter ?

```
param ftports array = [
  {
    name: 'test'
    value_id:resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', myVNet_name, 'mySubnet')
  }
]
```

can't get rid of the error "This symbol cannot be referenced here. Only other parameters can be referenced in parameter default values."

Answer (score 1):

> "This symbol cannot be referenced here. Only other parameters can be referenced in parameter default values."

It means that the `resourceID` value cannot be referenced directly with the default value in `Arm templates`. Instead of passing it directly, Use `reference` function to pass the resource ID in the default value `parameters`.

I created a `subnets` in virtual networks by referencing it with a default value and was able to deploy it successfully.

I've taken a sample template to create a subnet within a virtual network from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/scenarios-virtual-networks) and I modified the below script in `json` file:

```json
"parameters": {
"location": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "Westus",
},
"subnets": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": "[reference('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', myvn, 'subnet1').id]"
}
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Deployment succeeded and created in Portal:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I never tried your scenario but you can reference the existing subnet and then use its values:

```
resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2022-07-01' existing = {
  name : '${vnetName}/${subnetName}'
  scope: resourceGroup(vnetRGName)
}

var ftports = [
  {
    name: 'test'
    value_id: subnet.id // or whatever you need
  }
]
```